# Use sql to calculate a market penetration ratio?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `'transactions'` of purchasing activity:

```
customer_id, company, purchaseamount
```

and am looking for an sql command to output the "market penetration ratio" for a given company:

For example, I want to calculate:

(number of unique customer_id who bought from company == 12) / (total number of unique customer_id)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct customer_id) * 100  / (select count(distinct customer_id) from transactions)
from transactions
where customer_id = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct case when company = 12 then customer_id end) / count(distinct customer_id)
from transactions;
```

Answer (score 0):

The unique number of `customer_id`s is a single row, so you can just `cross join` it with the distinct count per company

```
SELECT     company, COUNT (DISTINCT customer_id) / cnt AS penetration_ratio
FROM       my_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT customer_id) AS cnt 
            FROM   my_table) t
```